# Dask Repartition by Index Not working as Expected, Resulting in 2 Instead of 3 Partitions

Tags: python, dataframe, dask, dask-distributed

I'm trying to repartition my dask dataframe by city. I currently have over 1M rows but only 3 cities. So naturally, I expect to have 3 partitioned dataframes based of off the parameter I included.

Code I'm using directly from the Dask documentaion site:

```
ddf_1 = ddf.set_index("City")
ddf_2 = ddf_1.repartition(divisions=list(ddf_1.index.unique().compute()))
```

I created a dummy DF below to help explain what I would like as a result. Below I have an imbalanced dataset based on City. I want to partition the DF based on the number of unique cities.

[image]

Ideal result:

1. [image]
2. [image]
3. [image]

However, after running the above code. I'm getting only two partitions where each of the two partitions include 2 unique indexes (i.e. Cities). I can't figure out why after explicitly indicating how dask should partition the DF, it results in 2 instead of 3 partitions. One thought is maybe since the DF is imbalanced, it ignored the 'divisions' parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the docstring of [`set_index`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.set_index.html), `len(divisons)` is equal to `npartitions + 1`. This is because `divisions` represents the upper and lower bounds of each partition. Therefore, if you want your Dask DataFrame to have 3 partitions, you need to pass a list of length 4 to `divisions`. Additionally, when you call `set_index` on a Dask DataFrame, it will repartition according to the arguments passed, so there is no need to call `repartition` immediately afterwards. I would recommend doing:

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'City': ['Miami'] * 4 + ['Chicago'] * 2 + ['Detroit'],
    'House_ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2],
    'House_Price': [100000, 500000, 400000, 300000, 250000, 135000, 269000]
})
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2).set_index(
    'City', divisions=['Chicago', 'Detroit', 'Miami', 'Miami'])
```

Alternatively, you can let Dask pick the best partitioning based on memory use by changing the last line in the above snippet to `ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2).set_index('City', npartitions='auto')`

Comment: Thank you so much. That is interesting though, I wonder why they created divisions parameter as such? Why not simply the number indicated in the divisions parameter? Just curious though.

Comment: It is actually not working. Its not partitioning them correctly. Partitions have more than 1 city.

Comment: The `division` parameter sets the "dividing lines" of the partitions, which is why it was created this way. You can read more [here](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-design.html#partitions). Sorry the snippet isn't working for you, when I check the partitions with `[p.compute() for p in ddf.partitions]` I only see one city per partition. I'm using Dask version `2022.2.1`.

Comment: I'll update my packages. Thanks.